# How to convert Mathml to LaTeX using MJAX?

Tags: javascript, xml, latex, mathjax, mathml

Mathml to Latex conversion through Mjax is possible or not? Need Latex equation from the mathml coding.

I'm able to convert mathml to tex. Is it possible to convert MathML to LaTeX through mathjax?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS_HTML"/>
```

I used this script but its not working properly, that what i expected here.

```
   <html xmlns:saxon="http://saxon.sf.net/">
   <head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7">
<script type="text/javascript" id="MathJax-script" async
  src="../es5/tex-mml-chtml.js">
</script>
<title>T&F LaTeX to MathML Converter</title>
</head>
<body onload="window.resizeTo(50,50)" id="mytst">
<p><eqntxt>##eqn1##</eqntxt> <math>
  <mrow>
    <mtext>div</mtext>
    <mo>&#x0020;</mo>
    <mi>D</mi>
    <mo>=</mo>
    <mtext>&#x0020;</mtext>
    <msub>
      <mi>&#x03C1;</mi>
      <mtext>f</mtext>
    </msub>
  </mrow>
</math></p>
</body>
</html>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS_HTML"/>
<script type="text/javascript">
function codeAddress() {
            var element = document.createElement('a');
                  element.setAttribute('href','data:text/plain;charset=utf-8, ' + encodeURIComponent(document.documentElement.outerHTML));
                  element.setAttribute('download', "page.html");
                  
                  document.body.appendChild(element);
                  element.click();
        }
window.onload = codeAddress;
</script>
```

Expected Output

```
<TEX>${\rm{div }}D = {\ }{\rho _{\rm{f}}}$</TEX>
```